# How to find eccentricity of the conic $3x^2+3y^2-2xy-2=0$?

Tags: conic-sections

How to find eccentricity of the conic $3x^2+3y^2-2xy-2=0$?
How to deal with the $xy$ term?
Can't understand. Help!

Why isn't the standard formula working here for eccentricity of an ellipse which states $e=\sqrt{1-b^2/a^2}$?

Comment: You can eliminate the mixed xy term by rotating 45°  Substitute x=t+u and y=-t+u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exchanging $x$ and $y$ would give the same equation. This would indicate that the line $x-y=0$ is a line of symmetry, and therefore one of the axes of the ellipse. Therefore so is the line $x+y=0$.

Therefore, we consider a change of variable: let $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$ so that $x=\frac{u+v}{2}$ and $y=\frac{u-v}{2}$.

Substituting these into the given equation and simplifying, we have $$\frac{u^2}{2}+v^2=1$$

Now the ellipse is in standard form, with $a^2=2$ and $b^2=1$. Using $b^2 =a^2(1-e^2)$ gives $$e=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: If you dont mind...why isnt the standard formula working here for eccentricity of an ellipse which states $e=\sqrt(1-b^2/a^2)$ ?

Comment: which standard formula?

Comment: The one i wrote above ^ http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eccentricity.html

Comment: this applies to the standard form of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

Comment: Got it !Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** For conics of the form $$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+cx+dy+e=0$$

$ab-h^2$

the way to determine the nature of the conic is to solve $ab-h^2$

In each case it is given by:

- hyperbola : $ab-h^2<0$
- ellipse : $ab-h^2>0$
- parabola : $ab-h^2=0$

Where c represents the length of the semi major axis and d represents the length of the semi minor axis.

To get this form you must first find the centre points by calling the initial equation f(x,y) and making $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$ and solving from here
for x and y to get the centre point (h,k).

Now you have these the new coordinate values are $u=x-h$ and $v=y-k$.

Then, subbing x and y in terms of u and y back into the initial equation you should find that depending on the nature of the conic, then it should come in the form of:

- hyperbola : $\frac{u^2}{c^2}-\frac{v^2}{d^2}=1$
- ellipse : $\frac{u^2}{c^2}+\frac{v^2}{d^2}=1$
- parabola : $u^2=4cv$

and now:

- hyperbola: $e=\sqrt{1+\frac{c^2}{d^2}}$
- ellipse: $e=\sqrt{1-\frac{c^2}{d^2}}$
- parabola: $e=1$

**NOTE** Dont forget the 2h in the original equation

Comment: Its an ellipse..according to your formula its coming e=0 !!! Haww!!

Comment: Ive made a mistake here, give me a moment and I'll correct it

Comment: You should also consider circle and pair of lines

Comment: No idea how wolfram got this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ellipse+3x%5E2%2B3y%5E2-2xy-2%3D0+eccentricity